# Accessing global object works with console log but not when accessing it in the chrome console

Tags: javascript

I am playing around with js, and how is `this` referenced with objects, I have made an object literal, you can see the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/85vztx6s/13/), which looks like this:

```
function makeUser() {
  return {
    name: "John",
    ref: this
  };
};

user = makeUser();
```

So, if I want to log this that works fine when I do this:

```
console.log(user.ref.user.name);
```

But, if I want to access the object in the dev tools in the chrome console, then I get `undefined` if I do `window.user`, why is that?

Comment: I don't get what you want. `this` is `undefined` (or the global object in sloppy mode) in the example call, I don't see how that "works fine".

Comment: What I meant by "that works fine", is that I get the name John logged in to the console.

Comment: I get the object when entering `window.user` in the console on your fiddle page. Just make sure to open the devtools in the context of the "Result" frame, not on the editor.

Comment: hey Leff, go here, and click button and you can see that you will get both names in console: https://codepen.io/mkdizajn/pen/gXwoaL?editors=1011

Comment: @Bergi yes, that was wrong, I had a console open in the context of the editor

Answer (score -1):

because `ref` is referencing direct parent (and that is window) ..it's like `self` 
 == 'window' .. so you can access the `name` like this:

```
window.user.ref.window.user.name
```

or

```
user.ref.user.name
```

because window is top most object, you can ignore it or write it

Comment: But, even when I try that, I get undefined

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "direct parent".

Comment: in case that OP asked `window` is `this` , isn't it?